# Upload image return empty file

Tags: c#, android, asp.net

I have problem with upload image file from Android to remote webservice in asp net c#.

The problem is that the image file sent from Android to the remote server is zero kilobytes; the upload worked, the image file name uploaded is correct in correct folder in the remote server and I don't have error in debug Android and in debug asp net, but this image is empty.

I would greatly appreciate your help.

Thanks in advance

android code in java class:

```
    File mFile = new  File("/storage/emulated/0/image_file.jpg");
    if(mFile.exists()){
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mFile.getAbsolutePath());
        bmp.recycle();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
        Request.addProperty("byteArray", byteArray);
    }
```

WebService in asp net c#

```
[WebMethod]
public string sendUpload(Byte[] byteArray, string fileName)
{
    string Path;
    Path = "D:\\Inetpub\\wwwroot\\myAppAndroid\\uploads\\" + fileName;
    FileStream objfilestream = new FileStream(Path, FileMode.Create, 
                                              FileAccess.ReadWrite);
    objfilestream.Close();    

    return byteArray + "; " + fileName.ToString();
}
```

First Edit question, I have error in this line

```
file.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);

[WebMethod]
public string sendUpload(Byte[] byteArray, string fileName)
{
    string strdocPath;
    strdocPath = "D:\\Inetpub\\wwwroot\\myAppAndroid\\uploads\\" + fileName;

    System.IO.FileStream file = System.IO.File.Create(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(".\\myAppAndroid\\uploads\\" + fileName));

    file.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
    file.Close();   

    return byteArray + "; " + fileName.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should write the content of the received file on filesystem:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public string sendUpload(Byte[] byteArray, string fileName)
    {
        string Path;
        Path = "D:\\Inetpub\\wwwroot\\myAppAndroid\\uploads\\" + fileName;
        FileStream objfilestream = new FileStream(Path, FileMode.Create, 
                                                  FileAccess.ReadWrite);
// here some code is missing
        objfilestream.Close();    

        return byteArray + "; " + fileName.ToString();
    }
```

you have a `Byte[]` as input that you never write on the server disk.

Comment: If he never used it, he'd have found the error by himself, because VS happens to mark unused variables and gives a warning. But he IS using it, just not writing it to filesystem, but returning it to the user (@ChevyMarkSunderland: why would you want to send one meg of image back to the user when he just sent it to you - he will have kept a copy and doesn't need it back... ;) )

Comment: thank you but I don't understand if the problem is caused from Android or webservice...

Comment: @ChevyMarkSunderland your webservice C# code is not writing the content of the file on filesystem. if you don't write the content on the filesystem the file will always be empty. you do must write something into the file to have a file not empty...

Comment: Okay, I have edited the webservice in the first post, I have error.